# taking all input elements value from piece of html

Tags: jquery

I got an html like this

```
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td >
            <img src="" alt="close" />
        </td>
        <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="addproducts" value="141420">141420
        </td>
        <td class="prd">
            <strong>
                <a href=""></a>
            </strong>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a rel="prettyPhoto" href=""><img src="" alt="Product"></a>
        </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td >
            <img src="" alt="close" />
        </td>
        <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="addproducts" value="1213143">1213143
        </td>
        <td class="prd">
            <strong>
                <a href=""></a>
            </strong>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a rel="prettyPhoto" href=""><img src="" alt="Product"></a>
        </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td >
            <img src="" alt="close" />
        </td>
        <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="addproducts" value="242424">242424
        </td>
        <td class="prd">
            <strong>
                <a href=""></a>
            </strong>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a rel="prettyPhoto" href=""><img src="" alt="Product"></a>
        </td> 
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I am trying to get values of all "hidden" "input" whose name is "addproducts" in to a string .I have tried some code like below(this code is based on my full html which i can't put here because of size and other problem.if i get the logic to solve this problem i can my self take care of this).

```
  var txt=    $(this).parent().parent().find(".antal").find("input:hidden[name='addproducts']").each(function () {
           $(this).val() 
        });
    alert(txt);
```

but this gives just an object as alert.Can any one give me a hand on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want, as it seems, to get a text made of all concatenated values, you may do this :

```
var txt= $(this).parent().parent().find(".antal")
    .find("input:hidden[name='addproducts']").map(function () {
       return this.value
}).get().join('')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/), you can change the selector according to your need. There were few fixes in your html like closing of `input` and `image` tags.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/CRskv/)**

```
str = $('[name=addproducts]').map(function(){
    return this.value;
}).get().join(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XckwS/2/)

```
    $(function(){
        var my_txt = [];
        $("input:hidden[name='addproducts']").each(function () {
            my_txt.push($(this).val());       
        });
        alert(my_txt.toString());
    });
```

EDITED code